# How can I map a key for my hero to start walking towards the fountain?

Tags: dota-2

In particular when I play Puck and I need to escape, I phase shift, wait for my blink dagger to get out of cooldown, and blink away (usually double tapping it which makes me blink in the direction of the fountain).

This keeps the screen in the old position and not centered on my Hero, so I'd like to map a key for him to start walking away until I can re focus and manually direct him.

Since I can be Dire or Radiant, the fountain location can vary.

How can I do that?